# JNI methods with more than one argument?

Tags: java-native-interface, jniwrapper, jnienv

I am new to JNI and I wanted to pass three integer to the below function

```
void pauseEffectJNI(unsigned int nSoundId)
    {
        // void pauseEffect(int)

        JniMethodInfo methodInfo;

        if (! getStaticMethodInfo(methodInfo, "pauseEffect", "(I)V"))
        {
            return ;
        }

        methodInfo.env->CallStaticVoidMethod(methodInfo.classID, methodInfo.methodID, (int)nSoundId);
        methodInfo.env->DeleteLocalRef(methodInfo.classID);
    }
```

Please correct me if I am wrong

What will come in this line 
if (! getStaticMethodInfo(methodInfo, "pauseEffect", "(I)V"))

(I;I;I)V or just (III)V

if my functions is void pauseEffectJNI(unsigned int nSoundId, unsigned int number1, unsigned int number2)   ??

Basically I want to know what if I want to pass more than one Integer

Thanks for the help ... Here is function I made ...COrrect me if i m wrong

```
  void pauseEffectJNI(unsigned int nSoundId , unsigned int number)
        {
            // void pauseEffect(int)

            JniMethodInfo methodInfo;

            if (! getStaticMethodInfo(methodInfo, "pauseEffect", "(III)V"))
            {
                return ;
            }

            methodInfo.env->CallStaticVoidMethod(methodInfo.classID, methodInfo.methodID, (int)nSoundId,(int) number);
            methodInfo.env->DeleteLocalRef(methodInfo.classID);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to figure out JNI method signatures by hand, when 'javap -s' will tell you the correct answer with 100% reliability. Use the tools.